# Call SQl procedure with input value

Tags: sql, qliksense

Please help me, using Qlik Desktop 2018 Patch 2, 12.44.3 version
I create sql procedure

```
SQL EXEC [Procedure] @WORKPLACE_ID=[$(vPara1)], @CHANGE_TS_VALUE1=[$(vPara2)], @CHANGE_TS_VALUE2=[$(vPara3)];
```

And call it Using Inside Data load editor section

```
LET vPara1 ='34534534'; 
LET vPara2 = '2018-12-01 00:00'; 
LET vPara3 = '2018-12-02 00:00';
```

My question is how it's possible to input value from App side(screen below): using filter, custom object, input box whatever and click on reload button to generate result from procedure by clicking load data

[Sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhfDm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is just add button next to chart and save values to variables. To achieve that use variable extension:

https://developer.qlik.com/garden/56728f52d1e497241ae697f8

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't get how to do it, an example would help to resolve the issue for sure